# How to run a .jsp file on a live server

Tags: html, jsp

I want to run a .jsp file on a live server. Here is the content of test.jsp:

```
<html>
<head><title>A Comment Test</title></head>
<body>
<p>
Today's date: <%= (new java.util.Date()).toLocaleString()%>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I want to run it at [tests.bendali.co.za/test.jsp](http://tests.bendali.co.za/test.jsp), all I get is the file content. Do I need to install Apache Tomcat on the server for it to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a servlet/JSP engine in order to run JSPs.

JSPs are compiled into servlets and executed at server-side, and generate HTML that is then sent to the browser. Without a JSP engine, you can't use JSPs.

Comment: So do I just upload the apache-tomcat server file onto the server? Or is there a special thing I need to do?

Comment: No, you don't. The owner of this server should install a JSP server and configure it to let its customers deploy Java web applications on it. This is far from trivial. If ypu want Java web hosting, search for a company providing one, like CloudFoundry, CloudBees, Google App Engine, Heroku, JElastic.